# How to use auto-documentation for XCode?

Tags: swift, xcode6, code-documentation

I just found this [plugin](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) for XCode and I want know if there is already such functionality in XCode implemented?

Because in PHPStorm you just have to type `/**`+Enter to auto create a comment block prefilled with all variables of a function.

Comment: I do not have to mention that PHPStorm is by far the best IDE ever!

Comment: I think Xcode not have something similar yet!! I use this plugin too to document my code.